# JavaScript PHP identifier in Smarty

Tags: javascript, php, smarty

I have JavaScript variable set to identify defined PHP variable located in .tpl file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var total_pages =   <?php echo $total_pages; ?>;
</script>
```

While I set PHP variable in .php file:

```
$total_pages = ceil($count / $records_per_page);
```

Somehow [Smarty template syntax](http://www.smarty.net/syntax_comparison) is different than PHP doesn`t allow JS identifier to work. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: So what is the issue? You are using Smarty and `<?php echo $total_pages; ?>` isn't echoing the var?

Comment: What is your question, are you looking for the way to assign a php variable to a Smarty view ?

Comment: @RhapX   @Sylvain-MARTIN as I said "doesn`t allow JS identifier to work". The php variable to a Smarty view thing

Comment: @IhabAbdel-Rahim We know what you said, but it's quite ambiguous.  What you make it sound like is you're needing to use `{$total_pages}` instead of `<?php echo $total_pages; ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Smarty variables inside JavaScript blocks in .tpl templates:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var total_pages = {$total_pages};
</script>
```

Don't forget to define $total_pages as Smarty variable using [assign](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.assign.tpl) in php:

```
$smarty->assign('total_pages', ceil($count / $records_per_page));
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed the assign variables part :)